# "Go to cursor" debugger command in Visual C++ 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual C++ 2019. In a previous versions of Visual Studio, using the debugger, there was a command to "go to cursor". I do not see this function in the debugger in Visual C++ 2019, was it eliminated?

Comment: Now you just click on the code there is a green play looking button at the beginning of each line of code when you hover over it.

Comment: Did you mean `run to cursor`?

Comment: If my guess is wrong, please provide more info about your issue and just describe `go to cursor` option in more detail.

Comment: Hi stfark, any update about this issue? Please let us know whether you have any concern and we are willing to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is right, what you want is `run to cursor` and it actually exist under VC++ 2019.

Under **Debug** process with breakpoint, when you use it, move your mouse cursor to the code line and then right-click on the line-> click **Run To Cursor**.

Or just run **Ctrl+F10** shortcut.

[image]